# Exclude rows with specific columns values from SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got table with following columns and data:

```
stock   quant
-----   -----
10      0
10     -5
10      1
1       20
10      1
10      88
5       1
```

What I need is to exclude rows with `stock_status = 10` and `quantity <= 0` at the same time. 
 
I need to have those rows with `stock_status = 10` but `quantity > 0` or the other way around.

So the desire output from this would be

```
stock   quant
----    ---
10      1
1       20
10      1
10      88
5       1
```

Thanks.

Comment: so what have you tried so far to achieve this? any query you already tried? Also you wrote you want to have lines with stock = 10, but in your expected result set you have lines with 1 or 5?

Comment: I have tried `HAVING` and now im thinking about using `CASE`. It should be something like SELECT * FROM table WHERE stock != 10 (AND AT THE SAME TIME) quant <= 0

Comment: that's called `filtering` and in SQL you do it through `WHERE` condition. so add a condition `WHERE quantity > 0`

Comment: Here is a SQL Fiddle Displaying the answer...
They beat me to it.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a3896/3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well you actually wrote the query yourself by telling us what you need to exclude...

```
SELECT stock, quant
FROM yourTable 
WHERE NOT(stock_status = 10 AND quantity <= 0);
```

You should follow a tutorial on SQL query (for example on W3school) as this is very basic and you should be able to do a query like that in less than a minute after following a very short tutorial for beginner.

I recommend this link :
[SQL Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp?PHPSESSID=300ae3404d5fa2612f238abeebb8869c).

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT stock, quant
FROM yourTable
WHERE NOT (stock_status = 10 AND quantity <= 0)
```

or, apply [de Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
SELECT stock, quant
FROM yourTable
WHERE stock_status != 10 OR quantity > 0
```